# Unable to save input data from HTML table cells into JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have tried to put input from a user into cells of a table, which was created using HTML and to save that data into a variable of JavaScript.

I was trying to get the data from rows cell of table to JavaScript variables one by one, but I'm getting undefined in place of data when alerting the data after summit.

HTML code

```
 <table border = "2" cellpadding = "6" cellspacing = "6" bordercolor = "white" bgcolor = "red" class="center" id="mytable" >
        <tr>
            <th style="background: white;">EDUCATION</th>
            <th style="background: white;">INSTITUTE</th>
            <th style="background: white;">PERCENTAGE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: white;">10 th</td>
            <td id="10inst"><input type="text"></td>
            <td  id="10per"><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: white;" >12 th</td>
            <td  id="12inst"><input type="text"></td>
            <td  id="12per"><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: white;">Graduaction</td>
            <td  id="gradinst"><input type="text"></td>
            <td  id="gradper"><input type="text"></td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: white;">Masters</td>
            <td id="masterinst"><input type="text"></td>
            <td id="masterper"><input type="text"></td>           
        </tr>

    </table><br><br>
```

JavaScript code

```
var inst10 = document.getElementById("mytable").value;
var inst12 = document.getElementById("12inst").value;
var masterinst = document.getElementById("masterinst").value;
var per10 = document.getElementById("10per").value;
var per12 = document.getElementById("12per").value;
var masterper = document.getElementById("masterper").value;
var gradinst=document.getElementById("gradinst").value;
var gradper=document.getElementById("gradper").value;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO !
I think this is because when you initialize your variables, inputs are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be add "id" attribute in input elements, not td elements or table elements

Like this;

```
<input id="12inst" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be 2 problems in your code:

1. Make sure you run your JavaScript **only after** you enter text in the input elements.
2. You have `<input>` element inside `<td>` element. It means that when you getElementById of the `<td>` - you are not yet referencing the '' element. And the `.value` of '' is really undefined. So to fix that:

   instead of

```
var inst12 = document.getElementById("12inst").value;
```

do:

```
var inst12 = document.getElementById("12inst").childNodes[0].value;
```

Full working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1dpg5j3q/

Comment: no its not working for me if you can please send me the full code of both html and JavaScript

Comment: Yes. I created an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1dpg5j3q/ just enter text into your table cells, then click button "invoke javascript" (this solves the first problem I mentioned about running JS only after entering text), then you will see the inputs in the console. The JavaScript code has my solution for the second problem I mentioned.